# Issue with char array, contains garbage

Tags: c, gps, raspberry-pi-pico, chararray

I'm trying to run one of examples delivered by Raspberry for Raspberry Pi Pico. It is an example to read data from GPS module via I2C.
Raw data from GPS should be stored in a variable `char numcommand[max_read]`, but instead of data from GPS, there is some garbage.
Here is the full code:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2020 Raspberry Pi (Trading) Ltd.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "pico/binary_info.h"
#include "hardware/i2c.h"
#include "string.h"

/* Example code to talk to a PA1010D Mini GPS module.
   This example reads the Recommended Minimum Specific GNSS Sentence, which includes basic location and time data, each second, formats and displays it.
   Connections on Raspberry Pi Pico board, other boards may vary.
   GPIO PICO_DEFAULT_I2C_SDA_PIN (On Pico this is 4 (physical pin 6)) -> SDA on PA1010D board
   GPIO PICO_DEFAULT_I2C_SCK_PIN (On Pico this is 5 (physical pin 7)) -> SCL on PA1010D board
   3.3v (physical pin 36) -> VCC on PA1010D board
   GND (physical pin 38)  -> GND on PA1010D board
*/

const int addr = 0x10;
const int max_read = 250;

#ifdef i2c_default

void pa1010d_write_command(const char command[], int com_length) {
    // Convert character array to bytes for writing
    uint8_t int_command[com_length];

    for (int i = 0; i < com_length; ++i) {
        int_command[i] = command[i];
        i2c_write_blocking(i2c_default, addr, &int_command[i], 1, true);
    }
}

void pa1010d_parse_string(char output[], char protocol[]) {
    // Finds location of protocol message in output
    char *com_index = strstr(output, protocol);
    int p = com_index - output;

    // Splits components of output sentence into array
    int no_of_fields = 14;
    int max_len = 15;

    int n = 0;
    int m = 0;

    char gps_data[no_of_fields][max_len];
    memset(gps_data, 0, sizeof(gps_data));

    bool complete = false;
    while (output[p] != '$' && n < max_len && complete == false) {
        if (output[p] == ',' || output[p] == '*') {
            n += 1;
            m = 0;
        } else {
            gps_data[n][m] = output[p];
            // Checks if sentence is complete
            if (m < no_of_fields) {
                m++;
            } else {
                complete = true;
            }
        }
        p++;
    }

    // Displays GNRMC data
    // Similarly, additional if statements can be used to add more protocols 
    if (strcmp(protocol, "GNRMC") == 0) {
        printf("Protcol:%s\n", gps_data[0]);
        printf("UTC Time: %s\n", gps_data[1]);
        printf("Status: %s\n", gps_data[2][0] == 'V' ? "Data invalid. GPS fix not found." : "Data Valid");
        printf("Latitude: %s\n", gps_data[3]);
        printf("N/S indicator: %s\n", gps_data[4]);
        printf("Longitude: %s\n", gps_data[5]);
        printf("E/W indicator: %s\n", gps_data[6]);
        printf("Speed over ground: %s\n", gps_data[7]);
        printf("Course over ground: %s\n", gps_data[8]);
        printf("Date: %c%c/%c%c/%c%c\n", gps_data[9][0], gps_data[9][1], gps_data[9][2], gps_data[9][3], gps_data[9][4],
               gps_data[9][5]);
        printf("Magnetic Variation: %s\n", gps_data[10]);
        printf("E/W degree indicator: %s\n", gps_data[11]);
        printf("Mode: %s\n", gps_data[12]);
        printf("Checksum: %c%c\n", gps_data[13][0], gps_data[13][1]);
    }
}

void pa1010d_read_raw(char numcommand[]) {
    uint8_t buffer[max_read];

    int i = 0;
    bool complete = false;

    i2c_read_blocking(i2c_default, addr, buffer, max_read, false);

    // Convert bytes to characters
    while (i < max_read && complete == false) {
        numcommand[i] = buffer[i];
        printf("raw data [ %d ]: %s \n", i, numcommand[i]);
        // Stop converting at end of message 
        if (buffer[i] == 10 && buffer[i + 1] == 10) {
            complete = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

#endif

int main() {
    stdio_init_all();
#if !defined(i2c_default) || !defined(PICO_DEFAULT_I2C_SDA_PIN) || !defined(PICO_DEFAULT_I2C_SCL_PIN)
#warning i2c/mpu6050_i2c example requires a board with I2C pins
    puts("Default I2C pins were not defined");
#else

    char numcommand[max_read];

    // Decide which protocols you would like to retrieve data from
    char init_command[] = "$PMTK314,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0*29\r\n";

    // This example will use I2C0 on the default SDA and SCL pins (4, 5 on a Pico)
    i2c_init(i2c_default, 400 * 1000);
    gpio_set_function(PICO_DEFAULT_I2C_SDA_PIN, GPIO_FUNC_I2C);
    gpio_set_function(PICO_DEFAULT_I2C_SCL_PIN, GPIO_FUNC_I2C);
    gpio_pull_up(PICO_DEFAULT_I2C_SDA_PIN);
    gpio_pull_up(PICO_DEFAULT_I2C_SCL_PIN);

    // Make the I2C pins available to picotool
    bi_decl(bi_2pins_with_func(PICO_DEFAULT_I2C_SDA_PIN, PICO_DEFAULT_I2C_SCL_PIN, GPIO_FUNC_I2C));

    printf("Hello, PA1010D! Reading raw data from module...\n");

    pa1010d_write_command(init_command, sizeof(init_command));

    while (1) {
        // Clear array
        memset(numcommand, 0, max_read);
        // Read and re-format
        pa1010d_read_raw(numcommand);
        pa1010d_parse_string(numcommand, "GNRMC");

        // Wait for data to refresh
        sleep_ms(1000);

        // Clear terminal 
        printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
    }
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

And here is part of the output:

```
raw data [ 0 ]: 0 Raspberry Pi Trading Ltd  
raw data [ 1 ]: rry Pi Trading Ltd  
raw data [ 2 ]:  
raw data [ 3 ]: Mu..z 
raw data [ 4 ]:  
raw data [ 5 ]:  
raw data [ 6 ]:  
raw data [ 7 ]:  
raw data [ 8 ]:  
raw data [ 9 ]:  
raw data [ 10 ]:  
raw data [ 11 ]:  
raw data [ 12 ]:  
raw data [ 13 ]:  
raw data [ 14 ]:  
raw data [ 15 ]:  
raw data [ 16 ]: C.`A`pGÅT-ï.. 
raw data [ 17 ]: .`A`pGÅT-ï.. 
raw data [ 18 ]:  
raw data [ 19 ]: Mu..z 
raw data [ 20 ]:  
raw data [ 21 ]:  
raw data [ 22 ]:  
raw data [ 23 ]:  
raw data [ 24 ]: ) 2020 Raspberry Pi Trading Ltd 
raw data [ 25 ]: ˝.L3'.T3_.MS›&S4—&MCA&C4)&UBµ%DTÖ.DEã.WV7.IF°$EXı#RE}#RP≈#FCa#CX1#ECE
```

Any suggestions what's wrong?

Comment: `uint8_t int_command[com_length];` is not standard C++. See [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Also, `char gps_data[no_of_fields][max_len];` is not standard C++ either.

Comment: Enable all warnings. See [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)

Comment: @JasonLiam thanks for pointing on this. This code is actually C, not C++. I'll fix the tag.

Comment: Change `i2c_read_blocking(i2c_default, addr, buffer, max_read, false);` into `int curlen = i2c_read_blocking(i2c_default, addr, buffer, max_read, false);` Then change: `while (i < max_read && complete == false) {` into `while (i < curlen && complete == false) {` You want to loop on the number of bytes actually read and not the maximum possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not check the result of the I2C read. Probably it did not read anything.

You need to know how many bytes were read or if an error has occurred:

```
int bytesRead = i2c_read_blocking(i2c_default, addr, buffer, max_read, false);
if(bytesRead == PICO_ERROR_GENERIC) { /* handle error */ }
else
{
   /* do your stuff */
}
```

This is definitely wrong

```
if (buffer[i] == 10 && buffer[i + 1] == 10) {
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I2C does not read anything. Now I need to find out why... LED on GPS is blinking, which means it has fix, so it should send data via I2C. So at the moment I have no clue why I2C does not read anything.